# Ionic - How to delay angular range slider update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I use range slider in my app and it works fine, but the problem is the code sends lots of range slider values to the server.And it causes some lags.I want to design that so it can send the only last value when user removes his finger from scrollbar.Is it possible ? If so what should I change from my code ? 
Thank in advance.Here is my code:
Html part

```
<div class="item range">              
               <i class="icon ion-ios7-sunny-outline"></i>
               <input type="range" name="volume" min="0" max="100" value="{{scrollvalue}}" ng-model="scrollvalue" ng-change="enter(scrollvalue,lighting.id)">
               <i class="icon ion-ios7-sunny"></i>

            </div>
```

And here is controller part:

```
$scope.scrollvalue=0;

  $scope.enter = function(scrollvalue,deviceId,id){


    var data2 = {
      credentials: $scope.credentials,
      scrollvalue:scrollvalue,
      deviceId:deviceId
    };
         //var ss = id;

             $scope.scrollvalue=scrollvalue;

    LightingClient.postLightings(serverUrl, data2, 10000)
      .success(function (response) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is to update your `model` only when the range input has lost its focus. [Blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) does exactly this. Just add the blur option to your model:

`ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"`

```
 <input type="range" name="volume" min="0" max="100" value="{{scrollvalue}}" ng-model="scrollvalue" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="enter(scrollvalue,lighting.id)">
```

Another option would be to delay the model update. For example you can set your model to get updated every 1 sec like this:

`ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"`

You can read more on [ngModelOptions here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

Comment: Fyi, if any future readers are trying to control the slider via another input linked to ng-model, you may find this question valuable http://stackoverflow.com/q/42605685/5797593.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I changed **ng-change** to **ng-mouseup** and it has fixed the issue with a delay and multiple requests to a server as I have been using ajax.

```
 ng-mouseup="enter(scrollvalue,lighting.id)"
```