# Dynamically update ion.rangeSlider ngModel in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, directive, angular-ngmodel, ion-range-slider

I'm trying to update the value of an `Ion.RangeSlider` when its bound `ng-model` scope variable changes.  The model updates when the `Ion.RangeSlider` is used, but not vice-versa.  Other inputs with the same ng-model update when the model value changes, so this must be some special case.

[image: 1]

Edit: Woo! Here's a snippet @lin :)  Also [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattgoodrich/p6h5L1u8/25/).

```js
var app = angular.module('ngModelIonRangeSliderDemo', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    
    $scope.someNumber = 10;
    
}).directive('ionRangeSlider', function ionRangeSlider() {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
         rangeOptions: '=',
         model: '=ngModel'
      },
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
         scope.$watch('model',function () {
            elem.ionRangeSlider(scope.rangeOptions);
         });
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.1.6/js/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.1.6/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.1.6/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.min.css" />

<div ng-app="ngModelIonRangeSliderDemo">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="wrapper">
       <h3>Text input updates slider, but not vice-versa.</h3>
       <input ion-range-slider ng-model="someNumber" range-options="{min: -100, max: 100, step: .001}">
       <br/>
       <input type="text" ng-model="someNumber" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I have tried all kinds of suggestions in over ten somewhat-related stack overflow posts (which is how I have set up the current `scope.$watch` scheme on the ngModel), but none have worked. There aren't any errors in my console.  What's wrong? Also, why doesn't it work without any mention of the model in my directive? Please let me know if there's anything important I have failed to include in this post.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle or plnkr Matt?

Comment: Definitely!  I haven't used them very many times, so it might take a bit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `slider.update()` inside your directive and you will be fine:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {

    $scope.someNumber = 15;
    $scope.apply = false;

}).directive('ionRangeSlider', function ionRangeSlider() {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
         rangeOptions: '=',
         model: '=ngModel',
         apply: '=apply'
      },
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
         elem.ionRangeSlider(scope.rangeOptions);
         scope.$watch('apply',function () {
          if (scope.apply) {
            scope.apply = false;
            var slider = elem.data("ionRangeSlider");            
            slider.update({
               from: scope.model
            });
          }
         });
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.1.6/js/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.1.6/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.1.6/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.min.css" />

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="wrapper">
  <h3>Text input updates slider and vice-versa.</h3>
  <input ion-range-slider ng-model="someNumber" apply="apply" range-options="{min: -100, max: 100, step: .001}">
  <br/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="someNumber" class="form-control" ng-change="apply = true">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I was concerned about the lag that appeared when clicking and sliding, but I discovered the model and $watch within the link function were not necessary with your fix, so I'll request an edit with all that's required in your answer for future readers.

Comment: @MattGoodrich But now the input model does not update the slider. Let me take a look at this.

Comment: Wow great catch..  As you definitely know now, it looks like both the model scope variable and $watch are necessary with your approach, but I'll keep trying too.

Comment: @MattGoodrich got it :) Check the updated code. I just added a simple switch handling by holding an trigger `ng-change` state.

Comment: Woo!  Could you possibly explain what's happening if you have a sec please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137269/discussion-between-lin-and-matt-goodrich).

Answer (score 2):

Extra demo, how binding ion.rangeSlider to input works:

http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/r5aox84v/

```
var $range = $(".js-range-slider"),
    $inputFrom = $(".js-input-from"),
    $inputTo = $(".js-input-to"),
    instance,
    min = 0,
    max = 1000,
    from = 0,
    to = 0;

$range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    min: min,
    max: max,
    from: 200,
    to: 800,
    onStart: updateInputs,
    onChange: updateInputs
});
instance = $range.data("ionRangeSlider");

function updateInputs (data) {
    from = data.from;
    to = data.to;

    $inputFrom.prop("value", from);
    $inputTo.prop("value", to); 
}

$inputFrom.on("input", function () {
    var val = $(this).prop("value");

    // validate
    if (val < min) {
        val = min;
    } else if (val > to) {
        val = to;
    }

    instance.update({
        from: val
    });
});

$inputTo.on("input", function () {
    var val = $(this).prop("value");

    // validate
    if (val < from) {
        val = from;
    } else if (val > max) {
        val = max;
    }

    instance.update({
        to: val
    });
});
```